# Empty File Explorer in Eclipse DDMS

Tags: android, eclipse, file, explorer, ddms

I am trying to access db files on my Android phone through Eclipse's DDMS. However, file explorer is empty. Ive tried restarting adb server, restarting eclipse, and it still does not work. My phone can be seen under 'My Devices' and is shown to be online.

Any idea why this is happening and what can be the solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

DDMS will not show the device file system. You can only view the file system of your emulator.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is first **launch the emulator** ,`then go the Window->show view -> other -> Android -> devices`.Then you will be able to select the device that is online,now go the file explorer,which which will show all the files related to that **specific device**.Another point need to be noted here is ,the files in the file explorer varies from **device to device**

Answer (score 0):

Choose The windows Devices. Then click The menu Reset Adb. After I try this method My File explorer Look Fine

Answer (score 0):

If the other suggestions do not work. You can try restart eclipse. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use CMD
note: will if hav root access in ur phone or if ur using GenyMotion or if ur use eclipse emulater
1.  D:>cd android-sdks\tools (e.g i have my SDK in D: drive) 
2.  D:>cd android-sdks\tools> ddms.bat
3.  select your device name 
4. then from d menu select Device 
5. here.......... is file Explorer
6. browse d file 
7. can this file open with "OPEN SOURCE" app call named "DB Browser for SQLite"
8. now open ur .db file here